# How to reload media parttion table after dd

Tags: partition, sd-card, gparted

When I overwrite the partition table with `dd` command I can't mount my new partition mmcblk0p1 because is not updated

I need to force reload partition table of SD-Card mmcblk0, I unplug and plug SD-Card for update /dev/mmcblkp1 or run `gparted` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for reload media.

I search a bash command for it.